# C, pointer to function in struct, warning "assignment from incompatible pointer type"

Tags: c, pointers, struct, function-pointers

I have a struct defined as follow:

```
typedef struct {
    char (*behave) (int*);
} BEHAVIOURSTRUCT;
```

this struct is defined in a .h file and it is included in the .c file
There i have a global variable (MAX_BEHAVIOURS is defined as 3):

```
BEHAVIOURSTRUCT bhvr[MAX_BEHAVIOURS];
```

and in the init i try to assign this, but here i get the warning: "assignment from incompatible pointer type"

```
void init() {
bhvr[0].behave = BHVR_line_follow; // here
...
}
```

the function i am trying to asign

```
void BHVR_line_follow(int *currstate){
....
}
```

by the sound of it my declaration in the struct and the pointer to the function are not from the same build, but in my opinion they are. But most likely i am mistaken.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is your function, and the function-type required, side-by-side:

```
void BHVR_line_follow(int *currstate)
char (*behave) (int*)
```

The function-type required takes an `int*` and returns a `char`.
Your function takes an `int*` and returns `void` (nothing).

To summarize, the return-type of `BHVR_line_follow` is wrong.